# Glassfish 3.1 deployment error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish

I'm developing a JavaEE application on Glasfish Application Server.
I'm developing so I'm continously deployig/undeploying the application.

Everything has worked great until few hours ago when I got this error while deploying:

```
error in opening zip file --  file zip non valid:
```

and

```
com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive
cannot be cast to
com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared.FileArchive
```

the server log doesn't report anything else, id did search on the net but seems noone has encoured on the same problem.

My war file doesn't contains any zip file!

Has anyone an idea on how to solve this?

Thank you in andvace

Comment: How are you deploying? manually? how was it built? what are the recent additions ( in terms of jar files) to your application?

Comment: just for info, ear,war,jar are basically zip files, that's why the error about a zip file is logged. It's a bit confusing.

Comment: so that's mean my WAR is malformed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

RENAME WAR FILE

seems amazing but after that everything worked again!

Probably some earlier deploy failed leaving some references to the broken application. This is just a guess anyway

Comment: I would just like to add that if you don't want to rename the WAR file, you need to do 3 steps to clean-up the previous deployment.
1) Undeploy the application through the GUI.
2) In the `applications` directory of your domain, remove the file that references your application.
3) If the application was deployed through autodeploy mechanism, also remove any references to it in the `autodeploy` directory.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have a file with the same name created int the deploy folder. You cleanup that file and redeploy it will work. You should probably do a restart before redeploying.